# TensorFlow object detection results showing 'N/A'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection, object-recognition

I'm training a deep learning model for custom object detection using TensorFlow **1.15** on **Google colab**. I'm using **ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_coco**. After some training (20k steps) with losses 1.5 ~ 2.5, I generated the inference graph and checked the training. But the results are showing "**N/A**" on some images.

I've already checked the label_map.pbtxt file and config file, both are okay. [labelfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atAPJ.jpg) [config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwUUt.jpg)

The first two labels are showing in results i.e., *pedestrian_crossing* and *turn right*. But the last three are showing as **N/A**.
Here's a result image: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btefz.jpg)

I'm following this tutorial: https://medium.com/geekculture/training-a-model-for-custom-object-detection-using-tensorflow-1-x-on-google-colab-564d3e62e9ef